# Select folder in ASP.NET MVC application to upload files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I want upload a file it's simply:

**Razor**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
```

or

**Html**

```
<input type="file">
```

But, If I want select a folder to upload all files than contains, is it possible?

Something like:

**Razor**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Folder, new { type = "folder" })
```

Showing a "select folder dialog".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that when using `@Html.TextBoxFor`. There may be another way to upload a folder, but I don't know of it.

However, you can change the file upload dialog to upload multiple files at once, which is essentially the same thing. [Here is a tutorial showing how.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Essentially, you need to add the following attribute to your file upload input:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", @multiple = "multiple"  })
```

You also need to add the `multpart/form-data` attribute to your Razor code to generate the form. Here is an example from that tutorial:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

At this point, you can select multiple files to upload. You can easily open the folder, hit CTRL+A to select all, then hit upload to upload the entire folder at once.

Please note that you'll need to modify the controller action to accept multiple files at once.

EDIT: Here is an example on how to handle this in your controller action, from the previously mentioned tutorial. Note that your parameter is an array of `HttpPostedFileBase` objects, each one representing a file you upload. Then, you iterate through each and save it.

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)  
{  

    //Ensure model state is valid  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)  
    {   //iterating through multiple file collection   
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)  
        {  
            //Checking file is available to save.  
            if (file != null)  
            {  
                var InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
                var ServerSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + InputFileName);  
                //Save file to server folder  
                file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath);  
            }    
        }  
    }  
    return View();  
}
```

Comment: May be it's a solution but without selection folder dialog